# No sound on an ASUS 1018p

Tags: 11.04, sound, asus

How can I enable sound in Natty? Everything is on but I get no sound.

Comment: Nice work solving it yourself. Once you get the chance, I suggest that you self answer this so it can be marked as solved. :)

Comment: Where do I go to enable Ubuntu sounds?

Answer (score 1):

Did you go to sound preferences and see if the laptops inbuilt speaker is default? .Also see if you enabled Ubuntu sounds

Comment: I solved this problem by enabling Ubuntu sounds.